# Question locked because too chatty?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, locked-questions

This question has been locked: [Efficient algorithm to find all the paths from A to Z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342101/efficient-algorithm-to-find-all-the-paths-from-a-to-z) because there were (apparently) too much comments under the original question. No arguing from me about that, although IMHO most of them were on-topic...

But I can understand the comments being locked, and the discussion moved to chat. However, now that the entire question has been locked, one is not able to answer the question anymore. Is this normal? I'd understand it if the OP had accepted an answer, but this is not the case.

Could it be unlocked please? Or if not, could someone explain the rationale behind locking an unaccepted question because there were too many comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is rare but normal.  When a question gets too chatty we can place a temporary lock on it (in this case one hour) so that the conversation moves to chat.  Since I checked the chat room and they've moved the conversation there, I went ahead and unlocked that question early.

Comment: @Bill - the system doesn't let you lock only the comments?  I guess this would be too much of an edge case to justify the feature.

Comment: @AdamRackis No, we can only lock the entire post.  We do get to select from three different reasons, so it *would* be nice if "offtopic comments" only locked commenting on the post and left voting and answering enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Locking a question because the number of comments it gets is normally done temporary. It is usually unlocked after X hours, and kept locked just for the time necessary to avoid other users adds more comments.

The rationale is that discussions on comments is frowned upon; if you need an extended discussion, there is the chat, and each SE site has its own chat room. If you need to talk about a question in particular, you can create a room for that purpose.
That is why two users start a discussion in comments, an automatic comments suggesting to continue on chat is added.

Comment: Yeah, I know "they" don't want too many comments. I didn't know it'd be lock for a certain amount of time. Thanks.